# Is the following sentence grammatically sound?

Tags: meaning, grammar, punctuation, collocations

sentence: Everyone, everywhere would be caught in the deluge of the tsunami of shit that we let rage rampant.

Something about the last three words feels off.

Comment: It's grammatically correct but very ugly and confusing because it's thrown a bunch of words together that don't really work together.  Why "a deluge of a tsunami"?  A tsunami is already a deluge.  How does a tsunami rage?  What does it mean for a tsunami to "rage rampant"?  Did you write this sentence yourself, or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: In addition to the points that @stangdon raised, a tsunami is also an unstoppable force of nature - no one "lets" a tsunami do anything. The writer of this sentence was trying for a very colorful and strong metaphor, but really missed the mark.

Comment: @stangdon and Canadian Yankee: thank you, thank you, loving the rave reviews, I did write that myself. I did just ask if it was grammatical or not though, not whether or not if was worthy of Shakespeare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could give some more information of what you would like to achieve. Guessing this is why you have a couple of downvotes on your question.

**Question**
So to simply answer your question: Yes, the three last words sound weird.

**Intension**
I am inferring that you are the writer of the sentence and you would like to make it more readable. Further implying that it is important set emphasis on `shit`. So lets see...

I think the whole sentence sounds weird because of duplicate words and to much emphasis. So lets break down the sentence:

`everyone, everywhere` sounds a little bumpy. Maybe `Everyone from everywhere` sounds more fluent?

`deluge of the tsunami` is a [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm). While `deluge of the` can be removed without substitution, it can set emphasis. But the problem with this part is, that `of` and `the` are each showing up twice in close succession:

> "in **the** deluge *of* **the** tsunami *of* shit".

I would suggest to remove `deluge of the` completely.

`we let rage rampant.`: The words `rage` and `rampant`, while not pleonasm, they still mean the same. Here again, it can set emphasis. But I would not put emphasis on two things in the same sentence. So I would drop the `rage` or replace `rage rampant` with only `loose`. Or a combination of: `we let loose so rampantly`

At the end the sentence would look like:

> Everyone from everywhere would be caught in the tsunami of shit that we let loose so rampantly.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism, it really was pleasantly informative. I learned a new thing today.